# Python PyMuPDF searchFor method not working

Tags: python, string, pdf, search, text

I am using PyMuPDF library in python to search for a specific text in a PDF document and then highlight it.

`pdf_document = fitz.open(pdf_path)
 for i in range(len(page_num)):

     page=pdf_document[page_num[i]]

     for item in search_terms:
         search_instances = page.searchFor(item)
         for inst in search_instances:
            page.addHighlightAnnot(inst)`

The PDF document image is as given below:
[image]

I am able to highlight all of the terms in the PDF document except for the search term 'Gross profit'. searchFor() returns an empty list instead of the co-ordinates. Is it anything to do with the poor quality PDF?.If that is so it should not work for the other search terms as well.It works for terms like 'Turnover' and 'Cost of Sales' etc

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's a non text PDF.

You have to use a OCR like pytesseract for convert it to a text pdf then use fitz for highlighted it.

something like that should work :

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path, convert_from_bytes 
from fpdf import FPDF

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = /pathto/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'

def string_stream(s, separators="\n"):
    start = 0
    for end in range(len(s)):
        if s[end] in separators:
            yield s[start:end]
            start = end + 1
    if start < end:
        yield s[start:end+1]


def multipage_simple(whole_text):
    pdf = FPDF(format='letter') #pdf format
    pdf.add_page() #create new page
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12) # font and textsize
    cnt = 1
    stream = string_stream(normalize(whole_text))
    for s in stream:
        pdf.cell(200, 10, txt=s, ln=cnt, align="L")
        cnt += 1
    pdf.output("multipage_simple.pdf", "F")

def get_text_from_pdf_with_ocr(file_name_to_image_pdf):
    res = []
    seq_of_images = convert_from_path(file_name)
    for img in seq_of_images:
        text = re.sub(REMOVAL_SPECIAL_CHARACTER_PATTERN, " ", string=pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
        res += [text]
    return res
```

then do :

```
doc = fitz.open("multipage_simple.pdf")
```

You could get the whole text by doing :

```
text_ = get_text_from_pdf_with_ocr(pdf_id)
whole_text = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, text_)
```